# Mussar work by Chacham Ovadia

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis, mussar-ethics, hacham-ovadia-yosef

Did,  Maran HaRav HaGaon Ovadia Yosef Ztk"l write any Ethical(mussar) work during his lifetime? And if he did,  do we have it online in english?

Comment: See Imrei Av it was written by his son Rav Avrahom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only works actually written by R. Ovadia that contain *mussar* are:

1. Anaf Etz Avot (anthology of commentaries/stories on Tractate Avot
2. Me’or Israel vol. 3 (collection of sermons and eulogies)
3. Eulogies printed at end of Chazon Ovadia - Arba’ Ta’aniot
4. Some *mussar* appears sporadically in his commentaries to Ruth (pub. in Chazon Ovadia - Yom Tov), Esther (pub. in Chazon Ovadia - Purim) and Passover Haggadah (pub. in Chazon Ovadia - Pesach).

At his Saturday night lectures he would include some words of *mussar*; some of these lectures were printed in a series called Shiure Ha’Rashal (later repub. in Mishnat Yosef) and a volume entitled Masah Ovadia.

Two other volumes entitled Halichot Mussar is a collection of *mussar* pieces (and stories) of R. Ovadia.

I don’t think any of the above are online or in English.